# Creating and adjusting variable names and values through defines

Tags: c++, variables, macros

I am attempting to create a friendly interface for a logging class in C++. The end goal of this exercise is to be able to create a single define that can change per level used:

```
MODULE_LOG(name, LOG_ALARM);
```

There are several levels but I only want to change the above define. e.g. to log messages as well it would change to:

```
MODULE_LOG(name, LOG_MESSAGE, LOG_ALARM);
```

The idea is that the code would have a printing define that would be defined/undef as requested in the MODULE_LOG definition. So if LOG_MESSAGE was not defined, then the message printing macro would be defined as empty otherwise if it is in the list it would print.

Seeing that I have not got anywhere with define/undef route, I thought of using variables. My idea is to create a set of variables based on the levels passed in. e.g.

```
#define LOG_LEVEL(lvl,val) \
static int LOG_LEVEL_##lvl = val
```

However, I hit another issue with using variadic macro's in the C++. I don't seem to be able to get the macro's to create multiple names (i.e. the user passes in LOG_MESSAGE and LOG_ALARM, only one of them gets created). Also, I have not been able to dynamically set individual values.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to define/undef the printing macro's using defines?
2. Can one use variadic macro's to iterate through a list passed to it and create the variable as required?

Thanks.

EDIT - Can't use boost.

Comment: Does LOG_LEVEL have anything to do with MODULE_LOG?

Comment: This can be done much more elegantly [using templates](http://www.templog.org).

Comment: @KennyTM - No, just an id to indicate different log levels that can be enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 2):

How about using an array to capture the varargs?

```
enum LogLevel { LOG_ALARM, LOG_MESSAGE /*, ...*/, LOG_UNDEFINED};

#ifdef LOGGING_ENABLED
#define MODULE_LOG(name, ...) \
LogLevel levels[] = { __VA_ARGS__ , LOG_UNDEFINED } \
for(int i = 0; levels[i] != LOG_UNDEFINED; i++) \
    printLog(levels[i], name) // or something
#else
#define MODULE_LOG(name, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: This can only work inside a function. Or you can define a function in the macro, and somehow see that it's called.

Comment: Of course, this will work only in a code block. It can be turned into an expression via a function. But one usually wants to log something _inside_ a function (or method), right?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Had a similar idea, but using a class parameters and functions to set static variables at start-up,. This then involves only a comparison at print time.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You can't `#define` inside a macro.
2. Not directly. With some effort, you can get ugly and barely working macros. I don't really recommend going this way, but here goes:

The first thing you'll need is to know how many parameters a macro gets. There's no direct way, but look at this (taken from [here](http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/)):

```
#define VA_NUM_ARGS(...) VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 5,4,3,2,1)
#define VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,N,...) N
```

Now you can do something like:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b 
#define A(...) CONCAT(A,A_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_1(x) something(x)
#define A_2(x, y) something_else(x, y)
...
```

You'll have to reopeat the above definitions based on the maximum number of parameters you want to support.

Comment: Hi, nope. I tried a test `A("domain-x")` but compiled down to `A_VA_NUM_ARGS("domain-x");` rather than `A_1 ("domain-x");`

Comment: You're right. I edited it in attempt to fix it, but didn't test it. These things are tricky, and may require some more fiddling, but I think the idea can work.